# How to access a Registered COM inetrop DLL via a Delphi 7 Program?

Tags: c#, vb.net, delphi, dll, com-interop

We seem to be encountering issues when trying to communicate to a Com interop DLL services via our Delphi 7 Program. But all other test programs in VB and C# seem to be fine.

Please find the specific technical details below:

a) We have a VB.net class library project that references to the installed DLLs and generates a COM interop DLL. Under the specific constructor a new application instance is created. Please see below VB.net sample code:

```
Public Sub New()

    CreateLog()        

    Try
        sw.WriteLine(Now() & " " & "Creating Sage.Accounting.Application")
        oApplication = New Sage.Accounting.Application()
        sw.WriteLine(Now() & " " & "Completing Sage.Accounting.Application")
    Catch ex As Exception
        sw.WriteLine(Now() & " " & "Exception-" & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

After the above project builds successfully, a COM inter op DLL and type library files are generated (Sage_200V9.0_Lib .dll and .tlb files). Corresponding log file items are also generated.

b) I tested the .dll generated above by referencing it in sample C# and VB.net test projects where a button event would create the application instance. This was confirmed by debugging and debug logs that were generated. See below code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private SAGELib As Sage_200V90_Lib.Sage_200V90_Lib

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    SAGELib = New Sage_200V90_Lib.Sage_200V90_Lib
End Sub
```

End Class

c) Now the .dll and .tlb files were moved to the delphi program's output directory. The .tlb file was imported to generate Sage_200V9_0_Lib_TLB.pas. Please see below sample code to create the COM object instance:

```
CoSage_200V90_Lib = class
class function Create: _Sage_200V90_Lib;    
end;

class function CoSage_200V90_Lib.Create: _Sage_200V90_Lib;
begin
 Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_Sage_200V90_Lib) as _Sage_200V90_Lib;
end;
```

d) Running the delphi program that refers to the above unit, the create function is called via a button event as follows:

```
oMMSV9  : _Sage_200V90_Lib; // MMS V9 Object
oMMSV9   := CoSage_200V90_Lib.Create;
```

It goes into the created TLB unit and it goes into the VB.net's project constructor. But when trying to create a new application instance that is "New Sage.Accounting.Application()", the delphi program hangs.

e) I confirmed that this goes into the VB.net project constructor by checking the log items (as mentioned in a) and it had only the following:
"
30/06/2014 12:15:33 Creating Sage.Accounting.Application
"
but no "Completing Sage.Accounting.Applications" log item. There was no exceptions either.

f) Additional Tests that I tried was as follows:
I unregistered and re-registered the DLL using the following scripts:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm C:\DELPHDEV7\EXE\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll /unregister /silent

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm "C:\DELPHDEV7\EXE\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll"
```

Both scripts seem to have done the unregister/register action successfully.

g) Another test that I tried was leaving the VB.net generated files where it was in the VB.net debug folder. Importing the TLB file and running the delphi program still had the same issues where the it blew up with following error:

```
Project ..exe faulted with message: 'access violation at 0x77deb72e: write of address 0x00090e54'. Process Stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
```

I was also able to confirm that the delphi program is using the specific dll by trying to build the test project mentioned  in b) and it had errored saying:

```
Error   4   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll" to "bin\Debug\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll' because it is being used by another process.  Sage_200V9.0_Lib
```

"
h) I also tried using the following script to generate the TLB file separately

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm C:\DELPHDEV7\EXE\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.dll /tlb:C:\DELPHDEV7\EXE\Sage_200V9.0_Lib.tlb
```

Importing this TLB file and running the delphi program still had the same issues.

i) The installed DLLs mentioned in a) are basically SAGE related DLL as follows:

```
Sage.Accounting.Common.dll,
Sage.Accounting.Common.PersistentObjects.dll,
Sage.Accounting.Financials.dll,
Sage.Accounting.PersistentObjects.dll,
Sage.Common.dll,
Sage.ObjectStore.dll,
Sage.Utils.dll,
```

For the VB.net project, the above references were from my GAC. I also tried copying the above DLLs in a local location. But the same issue occurs in both cases.

k) Additional info wrt COM class are as follows:
In the VB.net project:

```
  <ComClass(Sage_200V90_Lib.ClassId, Sage_200V90_Lib.InterfaceId, Sage_200V90_Lib.EventsId)> _
Public Class Sage_200V90_Lib

#Region "COM GUIDs"    
Public Const ClassId As String = "d1e254d1-37f0-481a-bc4a-0fce7d99e8cb"
Public Const InterfaceId As String = "0e9d9839-ecf1-47da-a4d0-9522f8c7c7bb"
Public Const EventsId As String = "f6a7099c-13df-4c81-ab84-0f4093d90409"
#End Region
```

The specific TLB.pas file has the specific IDs as follows:

```
IID__Sage_200V90_Lib: TGUID = '{0E9D9839-ECF1-47DA-A4D0-9522F8C7C7BB}';
CLASS_Sage_200V90_Lib: TGUID = '{D1E254D1-37F0-481A-BC4A-0FCE7D99E8CB}';
```

Something seem to prevent the delphi program to create the new application instance.

I am currently trying out different ways of registering the COM interop DLL and also make a C# version of the project to generate the COM interop DLL. I will also keep looking through stackoverflow for anything related.

But I wanted to  check if I should be doing something else.

Currently we have no idea on how to resolve it. So any help or related information would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think you should contact Sage developer support to ask about this.

Comment: If you properly initialized OLE in Delphi (OleInitialize(nil) is enough), then probably something wrong in the COM server. As David suggested, try to contact developer of COM server.

Comment: Thanks for the response Guys. I had already contacted the SAGE developers and they don't deal with Creating COM interops and associated type libraries.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Would you be able to clarify "OleInitialize" bit please? I don't think I used that on the Delphi Side.

Comment: COM is initialised automatically in a VCL GUI app

Comment: @user As David mention, normally OleInitialize called automatically for main thread when TApplication created. You need to call it manually only for other threads (if you use COM/OLE with threading). Probably it is not a case.

Comment: Ok so no need to try the oleinitialize. I will look it up anyway. I will also keep looking for other methods. Thanks guys.  I just finished the C# version of the project to create the COM inetrop and TLB file. But encountering the same issue on the Delphi side. Currently I am trying out out different ways of registering the DLL to check if there is any change or not.

Comment: Hi, The above mentioned COM interop DLL seem to be working fine in a win 8.1 environment where a sage application instance is created successfully within our Delphi App.  I had then thought it could be due to the difference in IIS version (Win 7 - IIS 7.5 and Win 8.1 -IIS 8.5). But the next test that I did was turn off IIS 8.5 service and the sage application instance was still created successfully. The key thing  is that additional sage assemblies were loaded up from the GAC in win 8.1 after the COM dll, but not in win 7. Is there something else I need to take into account for win 7?